# accessing swiftstack using keystone

Tags: endpoint, keystone

I have been trying to use keystone to connect to swift.

I want to create the endpoint using the command:

keystone endpoint-create --region $REGION --service-id $SWIFT_SERVICE --publicurl "http://$SWIFT_IP/v1/KEY_\$(tenant_id)s" --adminurl "http://$SWIFT_IP/v1" --internalurl "http://$SWIFT_IP/v1/KEY_\$(tenant_id)s"

I just want to ask, what should the publicurl, adminurl and internalurl be?

Answer (score 0):

What you have there looks correct.